# Remove dots from url via .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm working on a server status currently and everything works fine, except that I can't get my .htaccess file to put out an url like ark.kazuto.de/312142448.png because it grabs an IP.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+status\.php\?ip=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1.png? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)\.png$ /status.php?ip=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Can someone help me real quick?

Comment: What exactly is problem with this .htaccess?

Comment: I need to have the dots removed of the file name in the url.

Currently it would be ark.kazuto.de/31.214.244.8.png which is invalid due to the dots so I need to have it like this ark.kazuto.de/312142448.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+status\.php\?ip=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1.png? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.png$ status.php?ip=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now.

Can you tell me how to append another _get variable? 

Like `ip=VARIABLE1&port=VARIABLE2` so that it gets rewritten `/312142448-27015.png` or maybe replace the dots with - like `31-214-244-8-27015.png`

Comment: To replace all dots with hyphens use: `RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\.+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R]`